# Javascript and jQuery stopped working in Grails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I'm facing a very weird thing in my Grails application, all the Javascript and jQuery stopped working, even the simple things like this is not working or executing, I tried "Clean" and "refresh dependencies" but nothing changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert ("Hi");
</script>
```

Here is what is generated :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/myApp/assets/FB_favicon.png"
    type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon"
    href="/myApp/assets/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114"
    href="/myApp/assets/apple-touch-icon-retina.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/myApp/assets/main.css?compile=false"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/myApp/assets/mobile.css?compile=false"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/myApp/assets/application.css?compile=false"  />

    <script src="/myApp/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/jquery.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/JqueryCalender.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/JqueryPaymentPlugin.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/JqueryValidationPlugin.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/adsValidation.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/alertify.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/alertify.min.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/jquery.growl.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/jquery.session.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/photosValidation.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/test.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/utils.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/wordCharacterCounter.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="/myApp/assets/application.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <script src="/myApp/js/stripe-v2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            alert("Hiiii");
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>



    <div id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="http://grails.org"><img src="/myApp/assets/FB_Logo.png" alt="test"/></a> </div>

    <head>
        <script src="/myApp/assets/jquery.session.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    </head>

    <div style="padding-left: 30px;padding-bottom: 50px;transform:scale(1.5,1.5);transform-origin:0 0;">Languages :
        <div id="lang_selector" class="lang_selector">

            <a href="/myApp/grails/ads/test.dispatch?lang=ar_EG" title="Change language." class="lang_link">
                <span class="lang_flag opacitiy_not_selected">
                    <img alt="" src="/myApp/static/plugins/lang-selector-0.3/images/flags/png/eg.png" border="0">
                </span>
            </a>

            <a href="/myApp/grails/ads/test.dispatch?lang=en_US" title="Change language." class="lang_link">
                <span class="lang_flag ">
                    <img alt="" src="/myApp/static/plugins/lang-selector-0.3/images/flags/png/us.png" border="0">
                </span>
            </a>

        </div> </div>
        <div id='cssmenu'>

            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">



                <li><a href="/myApp/users/logout">
                    <b><u>Logout</u></b>
                </a></li>

            </ul>




        </div>


        <div class="welcomeMenu"><a href="/myApp/users/edit/1"> Welcome , user </a></div>

        <div class="body">

        </div>



    </div>
    <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">Loading&hellip;</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What may caused this strange behavior?

Comment: Grails wouldn't cause JavaScript to stop working. jQuery, OK, that's possible. But not plain JavaScript. Have you tried a different web browser?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa , i tried the Eclipse internal browser ,Chrome  and IE all the same result

Comment: Go ahead and post the html code that grails is generating.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa i added it to the original post

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to prove that JavaScript is indeed working. To do that, change your test from...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Hiiii");
    });
</script>
```

... to...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hiiii");
</script>
```

That change will make your test bypass jQuery.

After verifying that plain old JavaScript is working, you can take care of the jQuery problem. Which is that you're loading jQuery twice:

```
<script src="/myApp/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/myApp/assets/jquery.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

It looks like you've got a second copy of jQuery lying around and the asset pipeline is picking it up.

Comment: '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hiiii");
</script>'  is working , to solve the second probelm so how i can make the asset pipeline use one jquery only for example jquey 1.11.1

Comment: Find the jquery.js file and delete it.

Comment: after deleting them i got this "pipeline.DirectiveProcessor , Unable to Locate Asset: /jquery"

Comment: Them? It should have been a single file: jquery.js

Comment: I meant that file "jquery.js"

Comment: If the file grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js refers to the jquery.js file, you'll need to remove that line so the asset pipeline doesn't try to process it.

Comment: this what i have in application.js:   **//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require_self


if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
 (function($) {
  $('#spinner').ajaxStart(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn();
  }).ajaxStop(function() {
   $(this).fadeOut();
  });
 })(jQuery);
}**

Comment: i made a new grails project to test the jquery in it and worked fine , i also found 
  **`<script src="/Test/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/Test/assets/jquery.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/Test/assets/application.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>`**  so i think this is not the problem

Comment: Now THAT is how you troubleshoot :) Keep going and you'll be able to solve your own problem. Most likely, you are indeed loading jQuery twice; somewhere in all that JavaScript code. If you've been using source/revision control to keep track of your changes, you can go back in time and figure out which changeset caused the problem. If not... bring out the Tequila.

Comment: for the last days i'm trying to see if there is something wrong in my application that may prevents JavaScript or Jquery from executing , but i can't fine any !!!!! shall i copy my code to a new project ?

Comment: Well, we've already established that JavaScript is not the problem. It's jQuery. You can create a new project. That might fix it, although that won't tell you what went wrong. I'm willing to take a look at your source code, if you'd like: http://emmanuelrosa.com